# Customizing JWT generation not working in WSO2 APIM 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, jwt, wso2-api-manager

I tried to implement the steps given in WSO2 3.1.0 documentation (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/) for customizing JWT.

As given in the documentation, I created the custom JWT generator java class, generated the jar and placed it under WSO2 Home/repository/components/lib folder. Did the necessary configurations in deployment.toml for enabling JWT and restarted the server.

When i hit an API with the bearer token, i am getting the X-JWT-Assertion header in the carbon logs but when i decode it, it doesn't contain the custom claims that i added in the custom JWT generator java class.

It contains the standard claims as seen in the below image and not the custom claims that were added (current_timestamp, message).

Need suggestions on this as i have followed the steps given in the documentation.

[image]

Comment: Hi Suman, is your Custom JWT Generator jar also deployed successfully in <WSO2 Home>/repository/components/dropins folder?

Comment: Hi Tharika, I have placed the jar only under <WSO2 Home>/repository/components/lib as given in the documentation. Do, I need to place it under <WSO2 Home>/repository/components/dropins folder as well?

Comment: Hi Suman, placing the jar under plugins should automatically deploy it under dropins folder. Do you see the jar in the dropins folder?

Comment: Hi Tharika, I verified, after placing the jar under lib and on restarting the server, it also comes under dropins folder automatically. But, the issue is there and the custom claims don't appear in the X-JWT-Assertion header. And you have mentioned plugins folder above. I guess you are talking about lib folder.

Comment: Hi Suman, yes sorry I was talking about the lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out it is a OSGi bundle that runs on top of Apache Felix.

Please check following import available in sample code ([CustomGatewayJWTGenerator](https://github.com/wso2/samples-apim/blob/master/CustomGatewayJWTGenerator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/test/CustomGatewayJWTGenerator.java)):

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
```

See also sample pom.xml. It adds some information about OSGi bundle:

Here is the important part:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
            <Export-Package>
                org.wso2.carbon.test.*
            </Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>
                org.wo2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.*,
                org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.*
                com.nimbusds.jwt.*,
                *;resolution:=optional
            </Import-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you can see, it exports components as OSGi. See bellow my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.wso2</groupId>
        <artifactId>wso2</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CustomGatewayJWTGenerator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway</artifactId>
            <version>${carbon.apimgt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.orbit.com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0.wso2v1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Export-Package>
                            la.foton.wso2.apim.custom.*
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.wo2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.*,
                            org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.*
                            com.nimbusds.jwt.*,
                            *;resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <carbon.apimgt.version>6.6.163</carbon.apimgt.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I believe you just need to change package information in `<Export-Package>`, copy JAR file to `$APIM_HOME/repository/components/dropins` and restart server.

Please let me know if something goes wrong. If it works, please mark answer as correct to help others. :)

Comment: Hi Emilio, I have used the same files that you shared above but the jar build fails when packaging is left as bundle. Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked. Try to clone this git repo, compile and copy jar to dropins

Comment: Just 'mvn install' and check target folder for JAR file

Comment: Updated my answer with full pom.xml

Comment: Hi Emilio, I had cloned the same git repo before. I tried again by changing the <Export-Package> value to "la.foton.wso2.apim.custom.*" as you shared above from "org.wso2.carbon.test.*".  When I try to build using maven, the build fails with the error:  The JAR/ZIP file (C:\Users\dabbiru.mohan\.m2\repository\org\wso2\orbit\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.4.wso2v1\joda-time-2.9.4.wso2v1.jar) seems corrupted, error: invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Comment: Seems there is some issue with the jar - "joda-time-2.9.4.wso2v1.jar".

Comment: This is the complete error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:3.2.0:bundle (default-bundle) on project CustomGatewayJWTGenerator: Error calculating classpath for project MavenProject: org.example:CustomGatewayJWTGenerator:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\dabbiru.mohan\eclipse-workspace\CustomGatewayJWTGenerator\pom.xml: The JAR/ZIP file (C:\Users\dabbiru.mohan\.m2\repository\org\wso2\orbit\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.4.wso2v1\joda-time-2.9.4.wso2v1.jar) seems corrupted, error: invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Comment: Delete folder C:\Users\dabbiru.mohan\.m2\repository\org\wso2\orbit\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.4.wso2v1 and try again... The downloaded package seems to be corrupeted.

Comment: You can safety delete this folder because it is Maven local cache, it will be rebuilt automatically by script.

Comment: Hi Emilio, I tried by deleting the above mentioned folder. Now getting the error:  The JAR/ZIP file (C:\Users\dabbiru.mohan\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\wso2\axis2-client\1.6.1-wso2v40\axis2-client-1.6.1-wso2v40.jar) seems corrupted, error: invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Comment: Seems the git repo wasn't cloned properly. I will clone the repo again and try.

Comment: I don't think problem is in GIT repo, just delete entire Maven cache, I mean, delete C:\Users\dabbiru.mohan\.m2\ directory and try again.

Comment: Thanks Emilio for all the help, I deleted the maven cache and this time the jar got built successfully and also I am getting the custom claims that I added in the CustomGatewayJWTGenerator class. I tried by keeping the <Export-Package> value as "org.wso2.carbon.test.*" and "la.foton.wso2.apim.custom.*" as well. In both the cases it's working.

Comment: Great @Suman! Actually, <Export-Package> defines only what package is visible to callers outside of bundle. The "la.foton.*" is my sample and in this case, as you just downloaded sample from Github, I suppose it should be "org.wso2.carbon.test.*". In summary, when you create your own package, make sure you'll declare it in pom.xml, so MANIFEST.MF will be generated property.

Answer (score 1):

I have kept the default JWT properties and values that come predefined with the product as is and have added the one you told. Placed the CustomGatewayJWTGenerator jar in the dropins folder.
The JWT properties look as below now in deployment.toml. Please let me know if the configurations shown below are correct.

**[apim.jwt]**

enable = true

encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url

generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"

claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"

header = "X-JWT-Assertion"

signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"

enable_user_claims = true

claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever"

**[apim.jwt.gateway_generator]**

impl = "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomGatewayJWTGenerator"

Restarted the server and now when i test the API with JWT access token, the invocation fails and getting null pointer exception.
Error Details are as shown below:

**ERROR** {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} - Error processing GET request for : /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu. java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.generateAndRetrieveJWTToken_aroundBody2(JWTValidator.java:353)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.generateAndRetrieveJWTToken(JWTValidator.java:336)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate_aroundBody0(JWTValidator.java:319)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate(JWTValidator.java:110)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate_aroundBody4(OAuthAuthenticator.java:334)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:109)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate_aroundBody42(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:419)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:413)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody36(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:349)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:320)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:367)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:327)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:98)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:368)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:189)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:813)

Comment: Hello, did you solve this problem? I'm did what is in instructions and getting exactly same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this scenario locally. It was reproducible when we are using JWT access tokens to invoke the API.

But I was able to successfully get the custom claims in the X-JWT-Assertion header when using OAuth tokens. Please see the below image.

[image]

You need to follow [this documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/#customizing-the-jwt-generation-jwtself-contained-access-tokens) to do the customisation when using JWT access tokens to invoke the API.

Comment: Hi Tharika, i also imported the github.com/dsmohan/samples-apim/tree/master/CustomJWTGenerator project that you told works with OAuth tokens. I generated the jar, placed in lib folder and then invoked the API with OAuth token and getting the custom claims. Thanks for the suggestions. Just that now i need to figure out why the JWT token code jar isn't working as i answered before.

Comment: Hi Tharika, the documentation that you shared above for jwt access token says the CustomJWTGenerator jar is to be placed under <API-M_HOME>/repository/components/dropins. I am not sure if it is to be placed in dropins in first place or under lib folder. Another thing mentioned is to set the apim.jwt.gateway_generator.impl to your class name in the deployment.toml. But i didn't find this property in deployment.toml at all. Do i need to add it explicitly. [apim.jwt.gateway_generator]
impl = "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomGatewayJWTGenerator"

Comment: In deployment.toml i only have these properties related to JWT.                         [apim.jwt]
enable = true
encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
enable_user_claims = true
claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever"

Comment: Hi Suman, you need to explicitly add the property into deployment.toml as [apim.jwt.gateway_generator]
impl = "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomGatewayJWTGenerator". You can add the jar to dropins folder.

Comment: Hi Tharika, then should i also enable the property [apim.jwt] generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator" as well which is by default present and if yes, the value should be kept the default one or is to be modified to "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomGatewayJWTGenerator"?

Comment: Hi Suman this JWTGenerator is different from gateway_generator. So leave the default value as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the documentation that you shared for invoking the API with JWT access token. I cloned the GIT repository given in the doc.: https://github.com/wso2/samples-apim/tree/master/CustomGatewayJWTGenerator, imported the CustomGatewayJWTGenerator code into eclipse. After the import was successful, i could see a build path error in eclipse: **joda-time-2.9.4.wso2v1.jar' in project 'CustomGatewayJWTGenerator' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file**. Even though the error was seen in eclipse, i was able to build the jar using Maven. I placed the generated jar in lib folder and after server restart verified that  the jar was present in dropins folder as well. But somehow, the custom claims that i added in the CustomGatewayJWTGenerator java class are still not coming in the X-JWT-Assertion header. Is it something to do with the error that i got in eclipse after importing the CustomGatewayJWTGenerator project or am i going wrong somewhere else?

The CustomGatewayJWTGenerator java class:
[image]

X-JWT-Assertion header:
[image]

Comment: Hi Tharika, I checked the carbon logs after restarting the server with the CustomGatewayJWTGenerator jar placed in lib folder. I found an error related to this jar and i think that is causing the issue. Any suggestions. Error that i got : ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.util.APIKeyMgtDataHolder} - Error occur while initializing API KeyMgt Data Holder.Default configuration will be used.java.lang.ClassCastException: org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomGatewayJWTGenerator incompatible with org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.TokenGenerator

Comment: This error might come if the custom generator class is defined incorrectly in deployment.toml

Comment: @TharikaMadurapperuma any throughts about next NullPointer?